# php input stream size limitations

Tags: php, input, upload, inputstream

I am trying to read a raw input stream from php using `php://input`. This works for most files, however, files over 4MB are being ignored in the upload. I have set `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size` to 20M each thinking it would solve my problem, but it didn't. Is there another `php.ini` setting that needs to be configured or do I need to do chunking of some sort? If so, how would I go about doing that? Here is the `upload.php` code:

```
$fileName = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'];
$contentLength = $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];

file_put_contents('uploads/' . $fileName, file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Comment: FYI... I am sending the file via xmlhttprequest, passing a file object through the send method.

Comment: I figured this out. Php was running out of memory to put the whole file in the buffer, so I increased the memory limit with the php.ini memory_limit variable. It works, but it doesn't seem like the best solution. If anyone knows a way to read the php://input stream into a file in pieces so it doesn't exhaust the memory limit, please let me know! Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [`stream_copy_to_stream`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php), which directly pumps the content of the input into the file without copying it all into memory first:

```
$input = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
$file = fopen($filename, 'wb');
stream_copy_to_stream($input, $file);
fclose($input);
fclose($file);
```

---

Alternative:

```
$input = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
$file = fopen($filename, 'wb');
while (!feof($input)) {
    fwrite($file, fread($input, 102400));
}
fclose($input);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work, same results as before. Right now the only way I can upload larger files is to set the memory_limit to a larger size in the php.ini file. For some reason I can't even modify it with ini_set("memory_limit", "64M");

Comment: @srowley That's weird. I tested with stream-copying hundreds of MBs from `/dev/random` and the memory usage never went above 7MB. According to a comment on the manual page, `stream_copy_to_stream` does seem to misbehave sometimes. Posted "manual" alternative. If that doesn't help either, your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I'm really confused now.. Your first method actually works with a 672M file, but not a 5M file. I don't know why.

Comment: @deceze Is it possible to read how many bytes have been written to file with `stream_copy_to_stream()` using filename from a different `php` file while the file is being streamed to destination?