# How to upload large size image from android application to server in php using stream method or multipart method?

Tags: php

I just use the following php code but encoded image requires more memory so that i want to use stream method. Please anyone suggest me. Advance thank you.

```
<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];

$binary=base64_decode($base);

header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

$file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');

fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);

echo 'Image upload complete!!, Please check your php file directory……';
?>
```

Comment: do u check in ur php.in file max_upload_size?

Comment: yea sir. can you please tell me how the multipart form of image upload works?

Answer (score 0):

Just set a higher [`max_upload_size`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size) in your webserver's config.

Comment: thank you sir. but i have to code this using stream method. so please suggest me.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106009/php-input-stream-size-limitations