# how to make this xmlreader code more efficient

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a large xml file (~350mb) which I need to store into a MySQL table, as proper data stored in separate columns etc.

I have tried to use LOAD XML, but it has never succeeded - I keep running out of memory and nothing gets entered (I am on hosting that I have no control over the php ini, and any attempts to increase memory allowed with my own php.ini or within the scripts themselves (ini_set('memory_limit',-1) etc) have no effect.

So, I am now trying to use XML reader to parse the xml. My xml contains about 130,000 entries, each with 18 children.

My code has gotten so far - I can insert around 75,000 rows before I run out of memory or my connection 'goes away'.

My question is, how can I make this code more memory efficient?

code:

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

print("<br>starting<br>");

// connect
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(CONNECTION STUFF);

// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// open xml
$xml = new XMLReader;
$xml->open('../xml/jobs.xml');

$sql = $orig_sql = "REPLACE INTO jobs (jobref, date, title, company, email, url, salarymin, salarymax, benefits, salary, jobtype, full_part, salary_per, location, country, description, category, image) VALUES ";

$count = 0;
$chunks = 500;
$total = 0;

function escape_sql($unescaped) {
  $replacements = array(
     "\x00"=>'\x00',
     "\n"=>'\n',
     "\r"=>'\r',
     "\\"=>'\\\\',
     "'"=>"\'",
     '"'=>'\"',
     "\x1a"=>'\x1a'
  );
  return strtr($unescaped,$replacements);
}

// move to the first <job /> node
while ($xml->read() && $xml->name !== 'job');

// now that we're at the right depth, hop to the next <product/> until the end of the tree
while ($xml->name === 'job'){
    $node = simplexml_load_string($xml->readOuterXML());
    $title = escape_sql($node->{'title'});
    $desc = escape_sql($node->{'description'});
    $email = escape_sql($node->{'email'});
    $url = escape_sql($node->{'url'});
    $img = escape_sql($node->{'image'});
    $sal = escape_sql($node->{'salary'});
    $bens = escape_sql($node->{'benefits'});
    $comp = escape_sql($node->{'company'});
    $cat = escape_sql($node->{'category'});
    $loc = escape_sql($node->{'location'});

    // add to the sql query
    $sql .= "(".$node->{'jobref'}
            .",'"
            .$node->{'date'}
            ."','"
            .$title
            ."','"
            .$comp
            ."','"
            .$email
            ."','"
            .$url
            ."','"
            .$node->{'salarymin'}
            ."','"
            .$node->{'salarymax'}
            ."','"
            .$bens
            ."','"
            .$sal
            ."','"
            .$node->{'jobtype'}
            ."','"
            .$node->{'full_part'}
            ."','"
            .$node->{'salary_per'}
            ."','"
            .$loc
            ."','"
            .$node->{'country'}
            ."','"
            .$desc
            ."','"
            .$cat
            ."','"
            .$img
            ."')";

    $count ++;
    $total ++;

    if($count === $chunks){
        mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
        $count = 0;
        print('<br>inserted : '.$total.'<br>');
        $sql = $orig_sql;
    }else{
        $sql .= ',';
    }

    $xml->next('job');
}

$xml->close();
mysqli_close($mysqli);

print 'finished inserting data';

exit();

?>
```

Comment: Have you discarded already the idea of breaking up your xml into say 13 blocks of 10,000 entries?

Comment: I haven't personally run into this issue, but maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6106217/2748747

Comment: @ShawnMehan I haven't - I'm pretty new to php, I thought about this but couldn't find a good resource on how to accomplish this in my case

Comment: Have you tried to `expand()` the node into DOM and import it to SimpleXML? This would avoid additional XML serializing and parsing.