# PHP file_get_contents("php://input") missing request content

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-get-contents

I have an issue in php codeigniter, Posting data from client to server like below, and in server i used to read post data by file_get_contents("php://input"). It truncate the data and displaying only first 50 character. It was working fine in my previous server, now we have changed to new server after that it getting an issue.

```
var base_url = "http://www.mydomain.in/";
$.ajax({
             url:base_url+ "index.php/api/transactions/status",
             data: {"username":"logimax","passwd":"pass@2015","status":"Y"},
             dataType:"JSON",
             type:"POST",
             success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                      },
                      error:function(error)  
                      {
                console.log(err);       
                      }  
          });
```

Firebug Report:
We could monitor the post data and response in firebug like the below,

Request URL:http://www.mydomain.in/index.php/api/transactions/status
Request Method:POST

Request header: Accept:application/json, text/javascript,

Form Data
username:logimax
passwd:pass@2015
status:Y

Response:
string(50) "username=l

In server
Server side code: using codeigniter REST service.

```
public function transactionsByStatus_post()
{
    var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')); // Its getting truncate. Not fully displaying the values.

//Response sending as JSON Format
}
```

Comment: the question is , why do you read your inputs like this ? why not using `$_POST` for example ?

Comment: print_r($_POST); it also return truncated values. Output looks like Array
(
    [username]

Comment: then, check out your php.ini option `max_post_size` and increase it to be a fair enough;

Comment: I thought this and increased this also already post_max_size = 256M

Comment: what will happens when you post your request normally , without using ajax ?

Comment: Without using ajax and rest api , I could get the data by using POST method.

Comment: try with this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6106217/2359679

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the xdebug extension is enabled in your php.ini.

If so, perhaps try these settings:

```
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
```